# Missing Image name in windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am looking at couple of dumps, I am constantly encountering these statements in windbg when I use lmv m on a module.

```
start    end        module name
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
```

I never saw these messages before. I tried searching I didn't find much information about this . Any thoughts what the issue might be or what to check?

Comment: Does your module appear in the complete lmv list if you do not try to match anything?

Comment: What type of dump do you have?

Comment: I have a Mini dump file with full memory